# Problems querying items using lastmodifed in SuiteQL

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

I am having strange issues querying NetSuite using SuiteQL.

I am using a query based on TO_DATE: `where lastmodifieddate > TO_DATE( '2023-03-01 05:24:25', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' ) order by lastmodifieddate` for some reason NetSuite SuiteQL is only using the date part in the WHERE clause.

[image]

This seems to work: But this way I guess I won't get an index search:
[image]

Has anyone tried anything like this? I am trying to get items changed after a certain timestamp. But I only get update from a certain date ...

Comment: BTW don't mind the localhost links, we are using a authenticating proxy. That proxy adds the headers. This is a real NetSuite call.

Comment: Did you found the correct way? I am also facing same issue. 
Need to urgently find a fix

Comment: I am doing something like 
{
             "q": "SELECT id, lastModifiedDate  FROM transaction where lastModifiedDate <= TO_TIMESTAMP( '2023-08-25 18:27:00.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF' )  and NOT tranId LIKE 'IF-%'  order by lastModifiedDate desc"
} 
 But still I am getting "2023-08-25 18:30:00" in results

Comment: Strange the HH24 fixed it for me... Maybe a Time-Zone thing? What happens if you add: ' TZH:TZM' and use that as well in your query. NetSuite documentation is rather ppor on this ...

Comment: Andre can u pls elaborate. I need to fix this. How did you fixed using  TZH:TZM'?

Comment: What do you get when SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( '2023-08-25 18:27:00.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF' ) , TO_CHAR ( lastmodifieddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF TZH:TZM' ) in there as well? That might show some extra info?

Comment: NetSuite isn't really helpful in date selections ... The lastmodifieddate precision is 1 second, which is also not that great when you have multiple action in the same second.

Answer (score 3):

OK... It is an Dateformat thing ....

`YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF` is the "normal" way of doing things. Extra issue: it is the local time of the NetSuite instance. `TO_CHAR ( lastmodifieddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF TZH:TZM' )` results in `2023-03-01 09:10:19.000000000 +01:00`

```
{
             "q": "SELECT id, itemtype, TO_CHAR ( lastmodifieddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF' ) as lastmodifieddate FROM item where lastmodifieddate > TO_TIMESTAMP( '2023-03-01 08:43:58.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF' ) order by lastmodifieddate"
}
```