# How to fetch data from netsuite REST api with filter as lastModifiedDate in UTC format?

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api, oracle-net-services

Submitting a query like q=lastModifiedDate ON_OR_AFTER "15/01/2021" works as expected, but a query like q=lastModifiedDate ON_OR_AFTER "2021-01-15T11:11:00Z" gives the 400 error

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a full SQL SELECT statement which you can control the date and timestamp formats like this:

[Problems querying items using lastmodifed in SuiteQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76772507/problems-querying-items-using-lastmodifed-in-suiteql)

In SuiteSQL you have to use to_date or to_timestamp to convert your date/time string into the proper object type in the underlying Oracle database.